# Cache not being cleared when changing partial design

Tags: sxa, caching

I have a component that is cacheable within a placeholder where another component is placed, which is an SXA component.
When I try to remove the SXA component inside the placeholder, the cache doesn't seem to clear.

For clarity:

I have a Menu component with a placeholder where i can place an Sxa Language Selector

The Menu component has cache and the cache clears when I publish some change to the menu, but when I remove the language selector from Menu the same doesn't happen, the language selector is still there on the CD server.

These components are inserted in the page through a page design.

But when I insert these components in the presentation details of the page, everything works as expected.

My instance is 9.0 update 1 with SXA 1.6 with CM and CD server and its multi-site

And I added this patch

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <events>
        <event name="indexing:end">             
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
                <sites hint="list">
                    <site>website</site>
                    <site>Site</site>
                </sites>
            </handler>
        </event>            
        <event name="indexing:end:remote">              
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
                <sites hint="list">
                    <site>website</site>
                    <site>Site</site>
                </sites>
            </handler>
        </event>
    </events>
</sitecore>
```

One more thing my cache setting include the menu rendering and the SXA language selector.

[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend upgrading to the latest SXA where you will donut caching feature (it is there since 1.7 as far as I remember). Take a look here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/set-sxa-caching-options.html.

Comment: I can't upgrade to sxa 1.7 right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue.  Here is what I determined:

- If I went to `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` and cleared the cache manually, everything was fine.
- I determined that the Cache that was actually holding the Partial Design cache is the `SXA[CompositesXml]`
- I then noticed that there is a `Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.EventHandlers.CompositesXmlCacheClearer` processor in the publish:end event.
- After digging into that code, it seems that the `SXA[CompositesXml]` cache is only cleared if the partial design inherits from one of these templates:

  - `/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience
    Accelerator/Composites/Datasource/Composite Section`
  - `/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience
    Accelerator/Composites/Datasource/Composite Group`
  - `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience
    Accelerator/Multisite/Content/Page`

To resolve the issue, I inherited my Partial Design template from the `Page` template above.  Then after publishing the partial design, the cache was properly cleared and the content was updated.